# Local Storage is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import User from '../modal/Model.js'
import { createSecretToken } from '../util/SecretToken.js';

export const Signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(req.body)
  try {
    const { email, password, username, createdAt } = req.body;
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.json({ message: "User already exists" });
    }
    const user = await User.create({ email, password, username, createdAt });
    console.log(user._id)
    const token = createSecretToken(user._id);
    console.log(token)
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    res
      .status(201)
      .json({ message: "User signed in successfully", success: true, user });
    next();

  }catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

I am trying to store the token key in localStorage but it showing `local stroage is not define`.
As in above jsx component I am trying store it in localStorage for auth.

Comment: `localStorage` is a browser thing. You're working in Node.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is not a browser-based code environment. Usually, web browsers (like Google Chrome, Safari, FireFox, etc.) use `localStorage` to store small chunks of data in the user's computer securely on the website.

In browsers, when you use `localStorage` like the following example:

```js
localStorage.setItem("myKey", "myValue");
```

This is a built-in function that creates a file to that website's domain, storing whatever the developer wants in that file to save for later.

Now, because Node.js is not a web browser, it has no built-in way of storing data for later. The creators of Node.js have not fully implemented `localStorage` as a default method yet, because there is currently no reason to do so.

There are many ways to mimic this method. Here are 2 examples to store data in Node.js:

#### Example 1

For Example 1 I'm using the package `fs` to create a file called `localStorage.json` (you can call this whatever you want though) and I will create my own function to write JSON data to that file the same way `localStorage` would.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

function storeData(key, value) {
  if (!fs.existsSync("localStorage.json")) fs.writeFileSync("localStorage.json", "{}");

  const defaultStorage = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("localStorage.json"));
  defaultStorage[key] = value;
  fs.writeFileSync("localStorage.json", JSON.stringify(defaultStorage));
}

function readData() {
  const storage = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("localStorage.json") || "{}");
  return storage;
}

// Example of these custom methods

storeData("key1", "foo_bar");

readData()["key1"];
// Returns: "foo_bar"
```

#### Example 2

For this example, I'll use the NPM package [node-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage). This package allows you to use `localStorage` the same exact way you would in your browser.

```js
const LocalStorage = require("node-localstorage").LocalStorage;

// This package also uses files stored on your computer to function. You will need to specify an empty directory/folder to put the storage data in.
localStorage = new LocalStorage("./path/to/dir");

// Then, use it the same way you would in a web browser.

localStorage.setItem("key1", "foo_bar");

localStorage["key1"];
// Returns: "foo_bar"
```

Answer (score -1):

LocalStorage is something present in browsers available in the window object and it seems like you are using nodeJS environment.